# Display images from Gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am totally new to node and want to know how to download an image with grids. Please help me.
I use mongoose and node for storing images, side front nodeJs. I want to download an image using the grid in nodejs.

```
db.open(function (){
    gfs.exist({ _id: id }, function(err, found) {
       gfs.createReadStream({ _id: id }).pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, gridfs is the best thing you can use.

```
 if (fileExists(image_name) == false) { //it check that file exist or not   
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(image_name);
            http.get(url, function (response) {
                response.pipe(file);
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log('already exist.');
        }
```

I am using this in my code , hope this works for you.